# DevOps Pipeline Trigger on different branches but same commit

Tags: git, yaml, azure-pipelines, git-branch

There is a build pipeline that triggers each time if a branch is uploaded to the git-Repo on DevOps.

The yml file for the pipeline is in every branch
(It is limited to a directory in the Repo by the yml-file, but not to any branch or something else)

```
trigger:
 paths:
   include:
     - directory/anotherdirectory
resources:
- repo: self
```

I push the local develop-Branch to the DevOps-Repo and the build pipeline starts as expected.
Then I create locally a new release-Branch based on the develop-Branch, but without any change, so that **both branches point to the same commit**.
When I push the new local release-Branch to the DevOps-Repo, the build **pipeline does not start**. (No pipeline entry is created)

Is there something that recognizes, that the commit has already been build (in the pipeline), unless from which branch? Can I force to build the same commit when pushing different branches.
Or do I miss something.

I also tried to have a feature/1-Branch that builds and created a feature/2-Branch for the same commit and it also did not start the pipeline build, to exclude that it's a filter problem on the branchnames.

Comment: When I have a look on the Branches overview, and I pushed both branches that have the same commit - the first push creates/runs the pipeline - , I see that both branch entries point to the same pipeline (in the Status column).

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger:
 paths:
   include:
     - directory/anotherdirectory
```

This trigger means that pipeline will be triggered if there are any changes in `directory/anotherdirectory`. When you push branch without any changes - pipeline will be not triggered.
If you want to trigger pipeline always, you need to modify your triggers, or remove them.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that the trigger somehow must realize that it's not only pushed, but also changed in the directory.
But the directory filter must exist, because there are two pipelines for different directories.

I found an answer and will post it...

Comment: The answer I found was wrong, because of a mistake. I does not work, when I create a branch on an already via pipeline builded commit. It only works If I rebase on the previous commit - both branches had the same commit and were builded as separate pipeline run.
So my question is still not solved.